# Anyone using bigdata technology for customer-facing web applications

Tags: neo4j, bigdata, titan

I want to use bigdata technology for my application which has around 1 million users. My data model has connected data (Likes, Dislike, Friends) and it has lot of operation for example- Mutual friends, likes, education etc. Currently I am using Mysql for it which can not be scaled beyond a capacity.
I am thinking of using graph databases like (Titan, Neo4j) but I am not confident about the performance and real time response.

Is there any organization already using big data technology for such use case.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "bigdata technology"? How big are the data sets that you want to analyze? Which methods do you want to use? Have you heard of Hadoop (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop)?

Comment: I suspect it comes down to the queries that you're doing.  Medium is one example of a social network which is using Neo4j.  They have some good information out there on what they've done.  Some examples: https://medium.com/medium-eng/how-medium-goes-social-b7dbefa6d413 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hOI8DJ5i_k

Comment: I also recommend this post: https://medium.com/the-story/what-are-bloom-filters-1ec2a50c68ff  It has nothing to do with graph databases, but is really good ;)

Comment: By "bigdata technology" I mean any NoSQL datastore for the data and querying and processing framework or api. We have around 1 million entries in user table and we are storing like, dislike, friends, eduction info etc. These tables contains 40-50 million entries. Based on like, dislike, education,location etc a user is recommended with other users. All this should happen in milliseconds currently mysql is doing it well but we want to move to NoSQL because data is increasing day by day.

Comment: Both Titan and Neo4j list several companies using their technologies. http://thinkaurelius.com/affiliations/ and http://neo4j.com/customers/